# Dual GPU laptop, using old OpenGL lib

Tags: nvidia, opengl, gpu, gpu-driver

I run OpenGL in Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with a nvidia card. My laptop has a dual GPU (the nvidia one and the Intel integrated one).

I install the nvidia driver through the CUDA toolkit install (as I need both).

Because my laptop has 2 GPU cards, I have to install the nvidia driver with the **--no-opengl-libs** argument, which states not to replace GL libs (as they are the libs from the non-nvidia GPU).

My problem is that these non-nvidia GL libs are OpenGL 3.0 which is rather old.

What shall I do to make sure I use a more recent version of OpenGL?

The reference to the section of the [**Install Guide** here](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux-pdf) mentioning --no-opengl-libs is in page 20.

Comment: There's no need to use arguments. Installing the Nvidia driver does not affect the integrated Intel and its drivers.

Comment: My driver install is done installing the CUDA toolkit (because I need both). And they mention this option as for the driver side of the install [install guide here](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux-pdf), page 20. I have updated my post to mention the CUDA toolkit install, but this is a driver related problem.

Comment: That may be applicable to a multi-monitor desktop where the Intel Graphics is used for display and the Nvidia one for computation only, but even then the guide mentions they *could*, not they *would*. Not applicable to hybrid graphics laptops where you would be using one or the other.